# How to insert Tiles attribute to Thymeleaf HTML tag attribute value?

Tags: tiles, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf and Tiles 2 extras library. In Tiles I can insert an attribute to HTML tag attribute value. For example:

```
<script src="<tiles:insertAttribute='case1url' />" ></script>
```

But with Thymeleaf I can't insert an attribute to tag attribute value:

```
<script src="tiles:string='case1url'" ></script>
```